# c#, Microsoft Interop Excel library: resize in correct format

Tags: c#, interop

I am using c# and Interop library and winform. I have a problem with the pdf exported using this code to create pdf, it is working:

```
Workbook wkb = GetApp().Workbooks.Open(excelLocation);
wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outputLocation);

wkb.Close();
GetApp().Quit();
```

It is working but I have problems in the design. The page in pdf at 100% of size (normnal size) is:

[image]

Too small, I would like to see the table biggest.

when you open in excel size isnormal. why not in PDF exported file? Do I need extra configuration in `ExportAsFixedFormat`?

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to change the export quality -`wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outputLocation, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityMinimum);` or `XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard`

Comment: I tried standard. what is the meaning of this flag?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfixedformatquality). Did it work?

Comment: I will post the solution this afternoon, I had to set 4 pages to see right the table